# Field Collection vs. Entity View Modes with Field Group

Tags: 7, entities

I have been using Entity View Modes to organize my fields, have different display types, and use Field Groups to add bootstrap-style wrappers around my content.

As often as humanly possible, I have views and panels render nodes with these view modes to keep a consistent look throughout the site.

I keep hearing about Drupal Field Collections, and have a basic understanding that it goes further and makes an Entity out of the grouped fields.  Seems like a different approach to achieve similar results. It has a lot more uses, but also a lot more open issues, and needs other modules to integrate with Views and Features.

I'd love to hear some thoughts on this.

Thanks,

Ji

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jim -

I love Field Collections because it allows me to create "structures" of fields that I can tie to multiple content types. You can still use Field Collections with Field Groups (in order to create field sets and the like). Would definitely recommend for projects with lots of content types / data that needs organization.

Comment: Thank Alex.  Could you give me an example of fields that you would have on multiple content types?  Off the top of my head I can only think of something like term reference fields.

Comment: For me, it has been where I wanted to add certain objects (thinking high level) to content types. Let's say that I want all content types to have a field collection called "Object Metadata" with fields such as "age", "gender", etc. You could then attached that field collection to multiple different content types (in my case, we have a few content types that are fairly similar). Then if you wanted to add new metadata types (in this example), you'd just edit one place.

Comment: Thank @Alex Laughnan, you have definitely given me some things to think about!